# POST Request to external API resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error`

Tags: laravel, api

so i have a task that need to do POST to an external API with {{url}}/link-ec/submit (this is for example)

and i did with form request input, and end up with `500 Internal Server Error`

i'm using laravel controller for submitting this form

this is my controller

```
$dataSubmit = [
                "customerName"          =>  $request->input('customerName'),
                "mobilePhone"           =>  $request->input('mobilePhone'),
                "nik"                   =>  $request->input('nik'),
                "birthPlace"            =>  $request->input('birthPlace'),
                "birthDate"             =>  $request->input('birthDate')
];



$clientSubmit = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' =>             
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer token']);

$responseSubmit = $clientSubmit->request(
            'POST',
            'url/link-ec/submit',
            ['json' => $dataSubmit]

        );
        $responseSubmit = json_decode($responseSubmit->getBody(), true);

        return $responseSubmit;
```

in case you guys need the route and form to know the problem:

```
Route::get('/post-link', 'IntegrationController@submit');
<form class="form form-fifastra financing-form" method="GET" id="form-apply"
                                action="{{ url('post-fifada') }}">
                                @csrf
</form>
```

this is the error

[image]

Comment: in`$responseSubmit` use `form_params` instead of `json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the API cannot deserialize the request body. Try to json encode the body before sending it, because the API expect a json in the body.

```
$responseSubmit = $clientSubmit->request(
        'POST',
        'url/link-ec/submit',
        ['json' => json_encode($dataSubmit)]

    );
```

Comment: i've tried with your code, but it returns this "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: Look @ErandaDava it is now a different error for a different bug, we are using json_encode in my code snippet, and you got the error for using json_decode in the line:
$responseSubmit = json_decode($responseSubmit->getBody(), true);

Comment: okaay, i just realized that. thank you for your insight, i will workaround this error

Comment: maybe you can use:
  $responseSubmit = $responseSubmit->getBody();
(without the json decode)

since your response body is already an array